# Return values to new columns in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, apply

I have a df of sales data. I want to add two more columns that highlight important values within the other columns.

At the moment I have code that returns the values into the new columns whenever a sale is made. So if a subject appears in the `Sales` column, the corresponding values are indexed in the new columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = 5
N = 10

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Tom_$' : [500, 50, 10, 60, 50, 77, 30, 600, 40, 60],
    'Tom_c' : [100, 20, 40, 50, 0, 67, 90, 100, 0, 0],
    'Code' : ['nan', 'nan', 'Big', 'nan', 'nan', 'Small', 'nan','nan', 'nan','nan'],                                 
    'Sales' : ['nan','nan','Tom','nan','nan','Tom','nan','nan','nan','nan']})


df['Big'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.get(row['Sales']+'_$') if pd.notnull(row['Sales']) else np.nan, axis=1)
df['Small'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.get(row['Sales']+'_c') if pd.notnull(row['Sales']) else np.nan, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Code  Julie_$  Julie_c  Sales  Tom_$  Tom_c  Dollars  Cents
0    nan      500      300    nan    500    100      NaN    NaN
1    nan       40       20    nan     50     20      NaN    NaN
2    Big       10       70    Tom     10     40     10.0   40.0
3    nan       10       50    nan     60     50      NaN    NaN
4    nan       50       80    nan     50      0      NaN    NaN
5  Small       37       67    Tom     77     67     77.0   67.0
6    nan       30       50    nan     30     90      NaN    NaN
7    Big      900      100  Julie    600    100    900.0  100.0
8    nan       40       40    nan     40      0      NaN    NaN
9    nan       50        0    nan     60      0      NaN    NaN
```

This works fine, but I want to add another layer by using the `Code` column. If the value in this column is `Big` I want to keep returning the salesperson values until theres a new sale. If it's `Small` I don't care.

So the output would be:

```
    Code  Julie_$  Julie_c  Sales  Tom_$  Tom_c  Dollars  Cents
0    nan      500      300    nan    500    100      NaN    NaN
1    nan       40       20    nan     50     20      NaN    NaN
2    Big       10       70    Tom     10     40     10.0   40.0
3    nan       10       50    nan     60     50     60.0   50.0
4    nan       50       80    nan     50      0     50.0    0.0
5  Small       37       67    Tom     77     67     77.0   67.0
6    nan       30       50    nan     30     90      NaN    NaN
7    Big      900      100  Julie    600    100    900.0  100.0
8    nan       40       40    nan     40      0     40.0    0.0
9    nan       50        0    nan     60      0     60.0    0.0
```

I have considered using a similar method to returning the values like the `Sales` column

```
df['Dollars'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.get(row['Sales']+'_$') if pd.notnull(row['Sales']) else np.nan, axis=1)
df['Cents'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.get(row['Sales']+'_c') if pd.notnull(row['Sales']) else np.nan, axis=1)
```

But this only works when the value is at the same index. I'm getting a little confused. I'm not sure if I should fill the data down so there always values in the `Code` column.

```
      Code
0      nan
1      nan
2      Big
3      Big
4      Big
5    Small
6    Small
7      Big
8      Big
9      Big
```

Then I can select the important ones. But I'm reluctant to alter the original dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace values of `NaN`s in `Sales` column by `ffill` for forward filling by mask by forward filling `Code` is `Big` or `Small`:

```
#replace strings nan to np.nan first
df[['Code', 'Sales']] = df[['Code', 'Sales']].replace('nan',np.nan)

mask = (df['Code'].ffill() == 'Big') | (df['Code'] == 'Small')
df.loc[mask, 'Sales'] = df['Sales'].ffill()

df['Dollars'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.get(row['Sales']+'_$') if pd.notnull(row['Sales']) else np.nan, axis=1)
df['Cents'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.get(row['Sales']+'_c') if pd.notnull(row['Sales']) else np.nan, axis=1)
print (df)
    Code  Julie_$  Julie_c  Sales  Tom_$  Tom_c  Dollars  Cents
0    NaN      500      300    NaN    500    100      NaN    NaN
1    NaN       40       20    NaN     50     20      NaN    NaN
2    Big       10       70    Tom     10     40     10.0   40.0
3    NaN       10       50    Tom     60     50     60.0   50.0
4    NaN       50       80    Tom     50      0     50.0    0.0
5  Small       37       67    Tom     77     67     77.0   67.0
6    NaN       30       50    NaN     30     90      NaN    NaN
7    Big      900      100  Julie    600    100    900.0  100.0
8    NaN       40       40  Julie     40      0     40.0   40.0
9    NaN       50        0  Julie     60      0     50.0    0.0
```

Comment: Thanks @Jezrael. Just to confirm, this will `ffill` the `Sales` column when `Big` is in the `Code` column?